# Whats wrong with this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
    // the next line works fine
    $('#show-forgetForm').hide();
    $('#forgetForm').click(function() {
        // I can't see the form when I click on the link
        $('#show-forgetForm').show();
        return false;  
    }); 
})
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#forgetForm" title="show the form">show</a>
<form id="show-forgetForm">
     [...]
</form>
```

Comment: There are no obvious syntax problems. Could you please tell us why this doesn't work and/or what errors you are getting in the console or firebug.

Comment: the first line works fine! but when I click on #forgetForm link, the form still hidden

Comment: can we see your HTML, or better yet setup a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to look at.

Comment: could you provide example in jsfiddle?

Comment: This would be so much easier if you provided a fiddle... Sure it's still easy but you would probably get an answer faster if you had a fiddle we could work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change

```
<a href="forgetForm">show</a>
```

to

```
<a id="forgetForm" href="#">show</a>
```

That is because `$('#forgetForm')` tries to find an element with its **`id`**,  and not its **`href`**, attribute being `forgetform`

Answer (score 1):

Is "#forgetForm" actually your form and not your link? sure you didn't swap them?

The code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hkv5J/

Answer (score 0):

you're calling function() inside the function()?.
you can get over it maybe because this function is running infinite loop in background...